# Powershell - how to Start-Job with an ActiveDirectory credential

Tags: active-directory, authentication, powershell, windows-authentication

My client controls access to their database with ActiveDirectory. I would like to do the following:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Start-Job -Credential $cred { 
    #do some stuff with the db
}
```

This works fine for any local user but when on the vpn and entering my ActiveDirectory credentials this fails to authenticate.

I know that I can use `runas` to start processes as the ActiveDirectory user only if I provide the `/netonly` flag (it does not work otherwise). I thought the following might help

```
$cred = (Get-Credential).GetNetworkCredential()
```

but the resulting object is not convertible to `PsCredential`, which is what the `-Credential` parameter takes.

Related to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607315/difference-between-runas-exe-and-start-process-credential) but it seems I might have been asking the wrong thing.

Comment: Can you try adding `-Authentication Negotiate` to Start-Job, right after `-Credential $cred` ?

Comment: @RyanRies `Start-Job : The specified authentication mechanism "Negotiate" is not supported. Only "Default" is supported for this operation.`

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit about what it is that you're trying to do within the job -- are you trying to do database calls using "integrated security" ?

Comment: @Jaykul yes the client's db uses integrated security. The reason for Start-Job is because I'm loading a .Net assembly into the AppDomain and calling utilities in it that connect to the database. Since there is no way to unload an assembly Start-Job allows me to do this without locking the file for the duration of the PS process. I was hoping that I understood what was going on beneath the covers and could use the -Credential flag on the job to also provide the correct integrated security credential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to do Integrated Security SQL queries, you *might* be able to do it with the impersonation module. I haven't tried SQL, but there's a post on how to [use the PowerShell Impersonation Module for network share access](http://huddledmasses.org/using-alternate-credentials-with-the-filesystem-in-powershell/) on my blog, and I believe that it's the same network credentials you need for SQL server (e.g. the same as using runas with /netonly).

If you're just using the job because you thought it would let you change credentials for network access, then just get rid of that and use Push-ImpersonationContext instead. If you *need* the job for some other reason, then you have to call Push-ImpersonationContext *inside the job*, which means you have to get your credentials into the job (probably by serializing the password and passing it through as an encrypted secure string).

I can't test it right now (I don't have a domain or even a db server handy), so, uhm ... let me know if it doesn't work ;)

Comment: Actually, spoke to soon. This works outside of `Start-Job` but becomes problematic within it. The thing is that I'd have to call `Push-ImpersonationContext` from inside the job, and there is no `Read-Host` inside of there (to gather the password)

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to serialize the credentials to disk encrypted, and the decrypt them in the job (there is a version of "Get-Credential" on poshcode.org which does that), or pass it into the job as a parameter (I can't remember if that works, and I'm on a tablet right now).

Comment: It looks like the link to the blog post is broken :(